# android button does nothing

Tags: java, android, validation, button

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(edconsulta.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) 
            {       
                edconsulta.requestFocus();
                edconsulta.setError("Campo No Puede Estar en Blanco.");
            }
            else if(edconsulta.getText().toString().length() > 0 && edconsulta.getText().toString().length() <= 10 ) 
            {               
                String dni = (edconsulta.getText().toString());
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Consulta where consu_cedula ="+dni, null);
                            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                                do {
                     //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                        String nombre = c.getString(0);
                        String cedula = c.getString(1);
                          String modelo = c.getString(2);
                          String banco = c.getString(3);
                          double precio = c.getDouble(4);
                          double seguro = c.getDouble(5);
                          double cuota = c.getDouble(6);
                          int plazo = c.getInt(7);
                          tx1.append(""+cedula);
                                } while(c.moveToNext());
                          //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Registro Existente"+cedula, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            //toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);                
                            //toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            //toast.show();
                            bt2.setEnabled(true);
                            bt1.setEnabled(false);
                            dbHelper.cerrar();
                            }                               
            }
            else
            {
                tx1.setText("No hay nada");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The administrator runs the sql query but I do not vote in implementing any results

Upon clicking on partial matches does not throw me any result.

I have create an app In the app, for the button i used onClickListner.

Please helpme..

Comment: It's unclear what is wrong

Comment: Have you called `setOnClickListener(this)` on the button in question?

Comment: As @NasaGeek says, can you please provide the code where you assign the onclick to the button.

Comment: At the time to click on the button if this blank throw an error but once filled with the identity card number I do not vote no message